# How to remove automatically m. part from the URL with keeping the rest of the current link in full

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to automatically remove the `m.` from the URL, while keeping the rest of the current link in full, in order to switch from mobile mode to computer mode in Selenium by Python 3.8.2

https://m.facebook.com/*************

I have tried this code but failed

```
driver.get('https://m.facebook.com/***********').replace("https://m.", "")
```

Comment: just write it without...? I cant understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by just using the `replace()` function of the `str` class:

```
link = 'https://m.facebook.com/whatever'
link = link.replace('/m.facebook', '/facebook')
```

EDIT: After seeing your updated answer, what you were doing wrong is that you were trying to call the `replace()` function on `get()`. You need to call it directly after the string.

```
driver.get('https://m.facebook.com/***********'.replace("https://m.", ""))
```

Comment: it's working now .. very very very thanks my bro .. It's my first time on this platform  .. so thanks

Comment: Cheers, buddy! Welcome and always remember to share a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question, showing what you have tried.

Comment: thanks my bro .. but anther question .. is this code is right ?                           driver.current_url.replace('/m.facebook', '/facebook')

Comment: As long as `current_url` is a string, then yes, it *should* be right.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried in every way and it did not work this time .. I am very disappointed

Comment: try calling `type(driver.current_url)`. If the result is not `<class 'str'>`, then you can't use the `replace` function on it.